# Matplotlib - overlaying line chart on bar chart and aligning yticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a line chart over a bar chart, but both the ticks and the actual locations of the points aren't aligned. I would like them to be aligned. (Just a note I'm going to be plotting another set of data similarly (but reversed) on the other side, hence the subplots.)

Here's what I have so far

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
group = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55]
amount1 = [967, 975, 1149, 1022, 852, 975, 1025, 1134, 994, 1057, 647, 1058]
amount2 = [286, 364, 111, 372, 333, 456, 258, 152, 400, 181, 221, 441]

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2, sharey=True, figsize = (17,8))
ax1_2 = ax1.twinx()

# y_pos
y_pos = np.arange(len(group))

# plot men
ax1.barh(y_pos, amount1, align = 'center')
ax1_2.plot(amount2, group, color = 'black', marker = 'o')

# ticks
ax1.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax1.set_yticklabels(group)
ax1.invert_xaxis()
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()

# padding
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.05, hspace=None)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: Resulting graph]

I've tried setting the ticks, but the bar graph and line graph seem to have very different notions of that. I've also tried graphing both on ax1, but then the line graph goes way beyond the bar graph and they don't line up at all. I've also tried `ax1_2.set_yticks(ax1.get_yticks())` but this has a similar problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot both in `ax1`, and remove the `y_pos`, because at the end both of them share the `group` variable as `y` coordinate.

Then, you can add a `height` to the barh plot.

Here, it is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

group = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55]
amount1 = [967, 975, 1149, 1022, 852, 975, 1025, 1134, 994, 1057, 647, 1058]
amount2 = [286, 364, 111, 372, 333, 456, 258, 152, 400, 181, 221, 441]

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True, figsize=(17, 8))

# plot men
a = ax1.barh(group, amount1, height=4)
ax1.plot(amount2, group, color='black', marker='o')

# ticks
ax1.set_yticks(group)
ax1.set_yticklabels(group)
ax1.invert_xaxis()
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()

# padding
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.05,
                    hspace=None)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

And an image with the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the `ylim`s of both axes aren't aligned. The `y` of the `barh` plot goes like 0, 1, 2, 3 till 11. The `y` of the line plot goes from 0 to 55 in steps of 5.  To align them, you could just do `ax1_2.set_ylim([y * 5 for y in ax1.get_ylim()])`.

An alternative would be to also use `ypos` for the line graph. Then the limits simply could be copied: `ax1_2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())`.

Here is the sample code, with the second graph left out for simplicity:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

group = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55]
amount1 = [967, 975, 1149, 1022, 852, 975, 1025, 1134, 994, 1057, 647, 1058]
amount2 = [286, 364, 111, 372, 333, 456, 258, 152, 400, 181, 221, 441]

f, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1_2 = ax1.twinx()

# y_pos
y_pos = np.arange(len(group))

# plot men
ax1.barh(y_pos, amount1, align='center', color='turquoise')
ax1_2.plot(amount2, group, color='crimson', marker='o')

ax1_2.set_ylim([y * 5 for y in ax1.get_ylim()])
# ticks
ax1.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax1.set_yticklabels(group)
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax1.invert_xaxis()

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

The plot now has the 0, 10, 20 ticks darker as they come from `ax1_2`. Just call `ax1_2.set_yticks([])` to remove those.

PS: Still another way, is to forget about `ypos` and only use `group` also for the y-axis of `ax1`. Then the height of the bars needs to be adapted, e.g. to 4.5 as it is now measured in the units of `group`.

In code:

```py
ax1.barh(group, amount1, align='center', color='turquoise', height=4.5)
ax1_2.plot(amount2, group, color='crimson', marker='o')
ax1_2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim()) # no need for labels as the ticks have the same value
ax1.set_yticks(group)
ax1_2.set_yticks([]) 
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax1.invert_xaxis()
```